# react one defintion route path for edit and add form

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like create ONE Route path for form add and edit. That is posible? If yes how. If no, please let me know what is the best practice.
I must define route similar like that:

< Route path="/edituser/:id"  component={EditUser} />

< Route path="/edituser"  component={EditUser} />

Comment: I found solutions if you need define one router you should add "?" after parameters so that is example:
< Route path="/edituser/:id?" component={EditUser} />

Answer (score 4):

If you read the react-router documentation you will see that you can pass nullable params to the router.

it means that you can check for a param, then if its null then its an Add situation and if not its a edit situation.

in your case you should define you route like this :

```
<Route path="/edituser/:id?" component={EditUser} />
```

which is the id is nullable and can be pass or not pass.

and then in the `constructor` or `ComponentDidMount` check it like this:

```
if (typeof this.props.match.params.id === 'undefined')
    //Add
else
    //Edit
```

Good luck.